# SQL Server CE 4 Entity Framework 4.3.1 Code First accent-insensitive and case-insensitive search

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I'm using EF 4.3.1 Code First with a SQL Server CE 4 database, it works great it created all the tables and the database with no hassle

But now I'm getting this problem I'm querying the database using LINQ

```
using (var db = new PeopleContext())
{    
      var people = from e1 in db.People
                   where e1.Name.Contains("maria")
                   select e1;
}
```

I would like to get on the results each person which Name contains `María` or `Maria` or `maría` or `maria` - notice the accent in the i - í

I want an accent-insensitive and case-insensitive search

Thanks in advance for any help

---

**Update:** Ok, I found a way of doing this on .NET Side by using `string.Compare()`

```
string.Compare(string1, string2, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The IgnoreNonSpace flag will ignore accents and the IgnoreCase flag will ignore case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact supports only CI_AS (not CI_AI) - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174596(v=sql.105).aspx - so you must use another database product, or store a searchable version of your data in another column

Comment: Hey Erik thanks for your response, just one more thing since my database its really small just about 300 rows, is there any way to do an accent-insensitive and case-insensitive search inside a list?? linq to objecs =)

Comment: case insensitive, yes, using .NET formating, not so sure about accent insesnitive